# A quick process of peer-review?

Tags: peer-review

I submitted my paper to a Taylor Francis Journal on Sept 21. Only recently it appeared out for review on Oct 25 and now shows reviews completed. I suspect that it will come out as a rejection. It seems to me not possible for a paper to be reviewed in ten days around.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just wait till you get the decision. What else can we say?

Comment: I’ve had a paper accepted in 10 days… It does happen.

Comment: This depends on your field: Reviewing a paper in my field takes me on average about half a day net time. If I don't expect to have that time within the next two weeks I usually decline the review.

Comment: I’ve reviewed papers in four hours. Then when colleagues review mine they take months and months.